# How to build React components to be consumed by HTML application?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app, storybook

I have a React project created with `npx create-react-app` where I implemented a handful React Components. I don't really see this project as an "React application", as it's just a personal library of Components I consume in another project, an HTML web application rendered using server-side technologies. My goal  is to gradually replace parts of this application with React components. I don't really envision it becoming a single React application, my plan is just to replace the parts I think make sense to be developed with React.

I have no issue implementing these components - I'm using Storybook to organize the independent modules. But I'm struggling with the build process.

If I run `npm run build` I create a single application, based on the original React application code bootstrapped by `create-react-app`, which I essentially abandoned in favor of the Storybook setup. If I add the files generated by `npm run build` my project, I can't get React to render my components properly.

I managed to get a manual build process to work:

- In my HTML project I add https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js and https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js
- For each of my React components source files, I run `npx babel --presets react-app/prod src/MyComponent.js -o build/mycomponent.js`
- Then I combine all the `npx babel` outputs in a single `components.js` file, adjusting some repeated functions that appear on the top of all files, and suppressing the `import` and `export` statements.
- I load the `component.js` file in my HTML project, and I can create my components using plain JS:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(MyComponent, {param: value}, null),
    document.getElementById('myComponent')
);
```

Is there a better process to build my components to a single JS file I could consume in my HTML application?

Answer (score 0):

As you expected, the project should be a reusable module/ UI library (say the name is my-ui) for other projects. I did the similar thing before and just introduce my approach here. First, export the components as normal. Second, create an index.js. Third, import and export those components you exported. Fourth, if you are familiar with webpack, use index.js as the entry in webpack.config.js to bundle the entire project as one file. You can publish this package, or just use it locally.
Then in other projects, import my-ui, you can use any component exported from that module.